# How to list all the files with given extension from directory, using filesystem?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Since `filesystem` exists in experimental part of compilers and will arrive in the newest version of C++, how to list the files matching a given extension from a directory using it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator

Comment: The question isn't clear. Why not use Win32 API functions for this? Are you asking for a portable way? Efficiently querying files is something that depends on OS-specific implementations for performance. Iterating files one by one is going to be orders of magnitude slower than eg [FindFirstFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: why would you use Win32 API when a standard implementation exists?

Comment: I use modern C++ and for the clarity of code, I want to use "modern" things from the STL, according to the rest of my code.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly was the problem you hit?
Otherwise there's plenty of good documentation already available as linked above.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo first, because unimplemented "standard" ways aren't helpful. Experimental features are not standard, they are experimental for a reason. In this case, a naïve implementation that doesn't allow recursion is going to be very, very slow.

Comment: Why don't you use the Win 32 API functions like FindFirstFileEx and FindNextFile ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: filesystem is a TS and a boost implementation exists. Suggesting to use a platform-specific solution when a generic portable one **that's likely to be part of the standard** exists is bad advice.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo advice to which question? The OP asked about *searching*, not iterating over all files. Using a standard class that isn't fit for a specific purpose is worse

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the OP explicitly asked for a solution that uses the experimental `filesystem` library.

Comment: I currently consider question unclear, either you want a generic solution that uses `filesystem`, or you want a platform specific solution that uses the `win32` library. What is it?

Comment: I explained that I do not want to use a C API in my code, because the rest is in modern C++. Furthermore, I know nothing about Win32 API. I already finished the filesystem part of my code with the solution of Vittorio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator) and filter manually:

```
for(const auto& p : fs::directory_iterator("some_directory"))
{
    if(p.path().extension() == ".txt")
    { 
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You can create a nice wrapper as follows:

```
template <typename TF>
void for_files_with_extension(std::string_view dir, std::string_view ext, TF&& f)
{
    for(const auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(dir))
    {
        if(p.path().extension() == ext)
        { 
            f(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
for_files_with_extension("/home/someone/", ".txt", 
    [](const auto& p){ std::cout << "Found text file at " << p << "\n"; });
```

Comment: This isn't standard, and performance will be very bad. Imagine filtering 1000 files when there are only 1-2 matches. This doesn't search subfolders either. The question was how to *search* not how to iterate over all files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the question asks how to **list** all the files matching a specific extension **with `filesystem`**. Suggesting a non-portable solution such as the Win32 API is outside of the scope of the question and, in my opinion, inferior advice compared to using a standardized TS or `boost::filesystem`.

Comment: Note that the OP acknowledges the experimental status of `filesystem`: *"Since filesystem exists in experimental part of compilers and will arrive in the newest version of C++..."*

Comment: As you pointed out "matching a specific extension". Not iterating over everything. Using some standard class that only fits 10% of a requirement is not a good idea, especially if you have to deal with a lot of data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: iterating over everything and filtering by extension is a way of **"matching a specific extension"**. Is it the most efficient one? No. Does it answer the question, fulfilling the constraints chosen by the OP? **Yes.**

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer using a platform-specific solution, but be aware that it will be inferior to a solution using **portable** and **standardized** classes. You're also **assuming** that performance is an issue here, while the OP didn't specify any performance constraint.

Comment: In my directory, I will have almost only files with the specified extension (only few ones that does not match the extension). So I guess there is not performance issue.

Comment: Do take care of case sensitivity of the extension string.